# Deleted (but not cleared) voicemails not visible on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios

**Background**:

I have an iPhone 5, iOS 8.3, carrier Verizon, and I currently can't get voicemails because my saved voicemails are filling all the available space.

I've found several articles about how to delete voicemails, such as the following:
http://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-delete-all-voicemail-messages-on-iphone-in-ios-8/
http://www.askdavetaylor.com/ios-8-actually-delete-voicemails-iphone/

I've deleted the old voicemails, but I still cannot get new voicemails, so the deleted old ones are clearly still stored in a delete queue (as I've read they are supposed to be). The problem, though, is that I am apparently supposed to see a link to these deleted messages at the bottom of the Voicemail list.
It's not there -- there's just the short list of voicemails I saved, and then blank space.

Now I'm stumped, since all the resources I've found just assume the deleted messages will be accessible in this way.

**Question**:

Are there any relevant settings I could change to make the deleted messages queue visible (or would a Reset All Settings possibly do the trick)?

Is there any other way to get to the messages and delete them (perhaps I should just contact Verizon)?

Comment: Try restarting your phone now that you have made space, if that doesn't work try setting the date back a year.

Comment: @Tyson: Just an ordinary restart? I already tried that; I just tried changing the date, and it didn't work. I don't think I have made space, in fact, since I never was able to clear the delete queue, and when I test calling my phone it says I can't leave a message because the voicemail box is full. I think the messages are just sitting in a delete queue, but I can't figure out how to get to them

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by resetting the network settings from Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings (this course of action is actually recommended in the igeeksblog post I linked, but for the circumstance where Clear All is disabled rather than for the particular circumstance my phone was in). After this, I was able to call my phone and successfully leave a voicemail. I also tested out deleting a new voicemail, and it went into a Deleted Messages queue that is now visible at the bottom of my Voicemail Tab, as usual.

Comment: Reset network settings as explained by sumelic worked for us as well